# If $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\exists k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. GCD(a,b)=ak+bl, $l,b\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

I don't really understand the proof for this.
It says "consider a set $A=\{ax+by\mid x,y\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Then let the smallest element of of $A$ be $d$.Then $d=ak+bn, k,n\in Z$. Show $d|a$ and $d|b$ so that $d$ is the common divisor. Then show that if $m|a$ and $m|b$ then $m \le d$."

I don't really know how if $d=ak+bn, k,n\in Z$ then $d$ divides $a$ and $b$ also I know how $m$ dividing $a$ and $b$ makes it less than $d$. I can understand it being equal but not less than.

Comment: I have some issues understanding which parts you don't understand. Could you edit them as separate questions not one long sentence stating what you do understand and what you do not?

Comment: Also, what are you allowed to say regarding $a\leq b$? Can you deduce it from the statement $a|b$ and a,b being natural numbers or do you need to give greater justification in your course?

Comment: I think it's fair to say you can assume one is larger than the other

Comment: You can find the standard proofs in the linked dupe. If something is not clear then please ask questions in comments there.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, do Euclidean division of $a$ by $d$:  get $a=qd+r,0\le r\lt d$.  But then, $r=a-qd=a-q(ak+bn)=a(1-qk)+bn\in A\implies r=0$, by minimality of $d$.

So $d\mid a$.

Answer (score 0):

$m|a$ and $m|b$ implies $m|(ak+bn)=d$ and hence $m \leq d$.